# Trouble testing hello world angularjs behavior with capybara rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rspec

I am using RSpec with Capybara, and trying to learn TDD and angularJS. So I found this example angularJS code which is like a hello world example. It works when I load the page

```
<div ng-app="" class="hi">
  <p>Name: <input id="name" type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
  <p ng-bind="name"></p>
</div>
```

I want the test to confirm that it is working so I write this code in my test file.

```
it "has content after filling content" do
  visit '/playground'
    fill_in 'name', :with => 'Jimmy'
    expect(page).to have_text('Jimmy')
end
```

But it tells me

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_text('Jimmy')
   expected #has_text?("Jimmy") to return true, got false
```

The behavior of the application is supposed to print out the contents of an input as the user types into a textbox, and it works on the browser, but for some reason, capybara is saying that it is not working.